# find all items in list object

Tags: python

I would like to interrogate all new emails (one by one) and find the contents of them so that I can use the contents for another application.

My first step was interpreting the return values from a search done via the search attr of an IMAP4 object.  I'm trying to figure out what data is in a list that I have returned to me.
How can I examine the object tree via print?  Or, better yet, how can I get the contents of the email in a string?

For ex., I am returned the following via print:
`unseen email content: ['3 4']` from a variable named "response".
If I run `print response.__class__.__name__`, I get "list" returned.

I know that there is other data in "3", and "4", I just don't know what.

update: Specifically, this is the return of a call to an IMAP4obj.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')

Comment: Well, `response.__class__.__name__` gives you the name of the class of `response`. Try `print dir(response)` if you want a listing of all of `response`'s attributes.

Comment: OK, but I want to see all of the *data*, not just the options from dir, right?  I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: '3 4' is a 3 char string in a list! there is no other data! You need to provide more information, otherwise we cant help!

Comment: updated question. Hopefully this explains the problem a bit more- I'm getting a returned list from a call to a query of an IMAP4 object, but I don't know what the object returns.  I have read the documentation and it doesn't help me much in understanding what [3, 4] means, and so I would like to interrogate the object instead.

Comment: OK, I found this: http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the python docs ([here](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.search)) this example:

```
# M is a connected IMAP4 instance...
typ, msgnums = M.search(None, 'FROM', '"LDJ"')
```

it seems a tuple is returned, you can try,

```
print(type(typ))
print(dir(typ))
print(type(msgnums))
print(dir(msgnums))
```

try reading the docs, see if it can help clarify your doubts or even make your question clearer.

Comment: where in the docs is there info about what is returned from M.search()?  This is what I hate about the python docs... I have had nothing but dead ends trying to read them...

Comment: ok, I can see (and already sorta knew) that there is a string "OK" and a list [3, 4] returned.  What I would really like to do is get the content of any new email that comes into an inbox by polling it.  I should have clarified that in the beginning (updated q).  Does anyone have tips regarding this, or maybe another question on SO to point me to?

Comment: its very easy to use the python docs, IMP4 is a class object with all those methods. In this case I would go for the [IMP4.fetch](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.fetch), _message_set_ is integer that represents one message (3 or 4 as you said) and _message_parts_ should be a string of message part names enclosed within parentheses. I never used this module, but I'm guessing. Also could help if you use command line and try accessing it by yourself testing out the commands from the doc.

Answer (score 1):

You may try importing pdb and doing a `pdb.pprint.pprint(response)`

If it's a program running on your own machine, you can also do a `pdb.set_trace()` and play with  response.

The ipdb module has nicer versions, but it's not usually installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a debugger might help. If you are using an IDE with a debugger set a break point and introspect the objects.

If you do not use an IDE yet, try [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) in combination with [PyDev](http://pydev.org)